# can we change Default path(Installation) after installation completes, using PostBuild event? How?

Tags: wpf

each time I click desktop shortcut, application installs each time, this is because I changed the default location of my installed folder on drive and I have to change the folder location where my files gets installed. How can we do that using post build event so that after installation, my application should run from new location

Comment: Is this an app you created? How are you installing it? A Visual Studio Deployment project? WiX? ClickOnce?

Comment: Yes this is an app I am creating and installing it using Visual Studio Deployment project

Comment: How did you "changed the default location of my installed folder" and what did you change it to?